# How to make app's background blur on Android? Just like the effect when we call Siri on iPhone

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

> I've done with transparent background but have no idea how to make it blur

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my English skill. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This might be useful https://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/

Comment: you have to capture the screen first and then blur it.

Comment: How to capture the screen before my app start? Like if I open my app from the Homescreen, this screen will be the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Method Works For me

Make one java class BlurBuilder.java

```
import android.support.v8.renderscript.*;

public class BlurBuilder {
    private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.4f;
    private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 7.5f;

    public static Bitmap blur(View v) {
        return blur(v.getContext(), getScreenshot(v));
    }

    public static Bitmap blur(Context ctx, Bitmap image) {
        int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
        int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

        Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(ctx);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;
    }

    private static Bitmap getScreenshot(View v) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Add This in onCreateView of Activity or Fragment

```
final Activity activity = getActivity();
final View content = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
if (content.getWidth() > 0) {
    Bitmap image = BlurBuilder.blur(content);
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), image));
} else {
    content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Bitmap image = BlurBuilder.blur(content);
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), image));
        }
    });
}
```

In Gradle

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    renderscriptTargetApi *your target api*
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
  }
  ...
}
```